# How to search documents in within date range but based on text format info in Solr?

Tags: solr

All,

I wonder if there is a way can solve this problem that:

I have a lot of solr documents have field `pub_date`, but unfortunately with text format like`"20180901"`, if I currently want to search by pub_date within a range, how should I achieve it in Solr query?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you change the field type to a regular date type? Or if it is an existing core, why not add a new field `publication_date` that is of a regular date type?

Comment: Are all the fields named in the same format? i.e. is every value for the field `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: @MatsLindh  Not really, but for this question, we can assume that all docs have that field

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your fields have the same format, i.e. `20180901` - mapping to `YYYYMMDD`, you can use a regular range search. The lexiographic ordering of the strings will be the same as for the interval.

```
pub_date:[20180820 TO 20180901]
```

will give you any entries between (and including) those two dates. This assumes that there is no other formats used that cause other entries to be inserted in the sort order between those two values.