# How to search doc by checking if current date falls into available date range in Solr

Tags: solr

I have solr docs with start date and end date, what I want is to find all available docs that current date is between start date and end date? I wonder how to specify that query?

Some example is like this:

```
{
    uniqueId: "1jhk23-123424h-12312l3j1lj23lj",
    start: "20190101",
    end: "20191010"
}
```

Today is `20190125`, then this doc should be found

Thanks,

Comment: Can you confirm the schema definition of 'start' and 'end'?

Comment: It is just like in my question

Comment: Fields like that could be "string", "text_general" but also Solr supports three different date types - the answer will depend on how you've specified the type of these index fields https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html

Comment: Thanks, could you give a sample query for this question?

Comment: I can't because you have not told me the schema definition of the fields you are using :-)

Comment: Let us say it is string(cos I do not have access to schema too)

Comment: If you later confirm those are date range fields I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796753/solr-fetching-date-ranges

Comment: Thanks, it is not that format

Comment: If you are indeed using string maybe you can do q=+start:[* to "20190125"] +end:["20190125" to *]

Comment: Thanks, I will test this.

Comment: Isn't this the same underlying problem [you asked about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101425/how-to-search-documents-in-within-date-range-but-based-on-text-format-info-in-so)?

Comment: @MatsLindh Not exactly same, one is asking how to search that field, this one is how to search docs with current date in range.

Comment: @Kuan Sure, but the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: @MatsLindh Not really, this one is more about logic(which after I have already understood that how solr treat numeric format field). That one is more about usage( which I try to figure out how Solr work with numeric field ). Do not let the question context mislead you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your dates are in YYYYMMDD format (and not YYYYDDMM), the lexical sort order works fine. Using a regular range search will work in that case:

```
start:[* TO 20190125] AND end:[20190125 TO *]
```

Under regular circumstances this will fetch all tokens that has their sort order between those values.